# Bash ftp : put only newer files just like filezilla

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I can't believe I stuck there.

I would like to `put` only newer files in a bash ftp script.

Just like filezilla does:

[image]

I know it is possible with winscp, but I cannot believe this doesn't exist within the linux `ftp` command line tool.

Important Note: I can't SSH the server, so please **don't** suggest rsync.

Comment: Have a look at [lftp's mirror mode](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html). lftp is available in many popular distros so you will probably not even have to compile it yourself.

Comment: otherwise that would mean parsing the output of `MODTIME` command and compare it to the local file modtime, all that done in bash. Ouch!

Answer (score 4):

As @fvu suggested, I finally sorted this out with [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html):

```
lftp -u <username>,<password> <host> << EOS
set ssl:verify-certificate no
set ftp:ssl-allow no
set ftp:ssl-protect-list no
mirror -R --only-newer --parallel=10 <localfolder> <remotefolder>
quit
EOS
```